# Problem with solving equation with Hyperbolic functions $ 2\cosh(2x) - \sinh(2x) = 2 $

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I want to solve the following equation for real values of $x$, by substituting the exponential forms of the hyperbolic functions.
\begin{equation}
2\cosh(2x) - \sinh(2x) = 2
\end{equation}
If someone could help me I would be most grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you expand the hyperbolic functions into the exponential form, what equation do you get?

Comment: \begin{equation}
e^{2x} + 3e^{-2x} = 4
\end{equation}

Comment: Using definition of hyperbolic functions, you will get the equation of $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Now set $y = e^{2x}$ and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, the following formula $$\color{blue}{\cosh \theta=\frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}}$$ & $$\color{blue}{\sinh \theta=\frac{e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta}}{2}}$$
Now, we have $$2\cosh(2x)-\sinh(2x)=2$$ $$2\left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}\right)=2$$
$$\frac{2e^{2x}+2e^{-2x}-e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}=2$$ $$\frac{e^{2x}+3e^{-2x}}{2}=2$$
 $$e^{2x}+\frac{3}{e^{-2x}}=4$$ $$e^{4x}-4e^{2x}+3=0$$  we have $$(e^{2x}-1)(e^{2x}-3)=0$$ $$\text{if}\ e^{2x}-1=0\iff e^{2x}= 1 \iff 2x=\ln 1\iff \color{blue}{x=0} $$ $$\text{if}\ e^{2x}-3=0\iff e^{2x}=3 \iff 2x=\ln 3\iff \color{blue}{x=\frac{1}{2}\ln 3=\ln\sqrt{3}} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cosh(2x)-\sinh(2x)=2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-2+2\cosh(2x)-\sinh(2x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-2\sinh(x)(\cosh(x)-2\sinh(x))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sinh(x)(\cosh(x)-2\sinh(x))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sinh(x)=0\vee\cosh(x)-2\sinh(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sinh(x)=0\vee\cosh(x)=2\sinh(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sinh(x)=0\vee\coth(x)=2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sinh(x)=0\vee x=\coth^{-1}(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\sinh^{-1}(0)\vee x=\coth^{-1}(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=0\vee x=\coth^{-1}(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=0\vee x=\frac{\ln(3)}{2}$$